# Should exp2 be faster than exp?

Tags: math, floating-point

I'm mostly interested in the "exp" and "exp2" functions in C/C++, but this question is probably more related to the IEEE 754 standard than specific language features.

In a homework problem I did some 10 years ago, which tries to rank different floating point operations by the cycles needed, the C function

```
double exp2 (double)
```

appear to be slightly faster than

```
double exp (double)
```

Given that "double" uses a binary representation for the mantissa, I feel this result is reasonable.

Today, however, after testing the two again in several different ways, I could not see any measurable differences. So my questions are

- Should exp2 be (theoretically) faster than exp? and
- Should there be any measurable differences? and
- Has the answer changed in the recent years?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There are a number of platforms that don't take much care with their math library on which `exp2(x)` is simply implemented as `exp(x * log(2))` or vice-versa.  These implementations do not deliver good accuracy (or especially good performance), but they are fairly common.  On platforms that do this, one function is exactly as costly as the other but for the cost of an extra multiply, and whichever gets the extra multiply will be the slower of the two.

On platforms that aggressively tune the math library and try to deliver good accuracy, the two functions are very similar in performance.  Generating the exponent of the result is easier with `exp2`, but getting a high-accuracy significand can require slightly more work; the two factors roughly even out to the point that performance is usually equivalent within a factor of 10-15%.  Speaking very broadly, `exp2` is usually the faster of the two.

Answer (score 2):

I made some measurements, I hope some of you will find it useful.

### Conditions:

- [Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5-2620 v2 @ 2.10GHz](http://www.cpu-world.com/CPUs/Xeon/Intel-Xeon%20E5-2620%20v2.html) (the server had high CPU load during the test)
- Compiler version: g++ (Ubuntu 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.12) 5.4.0 20160609
- Compiler options: `-static -std=gnu++0x -ffast-math -Ofast -flto`

### The code:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <random>
#include <cmath>
#include <chrono>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    double g = 1/log(2);
    mt19937 engine(1000);
    uniform_real_distribution<double> u(0, 1);
    double sum = 0;
    
    auto begin = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();

    for (int i = 0; i < 1e7/4; ++i) // for non-parallel, `for (int i = 0; i < 1e7; ++i)`
    {
        sum += exp2(u(engine)*g);   // for exp versions, sum += exp(u(engine)); for empty versions, sum += u(engine)*g;
        sum += exp2(u(engine)*g);   // removed for non-parallel
        sum += exp2(u(engine)*g);   // removed for non-parallel
        sum += exp2(u(engine)*g);   // removed for non-parallel
    }

    auto end = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
    cout << chrono::duration_cast<chrono::nanoseconds>(end - begin).count()/1000./1000 << "ms" << "\t"
         << sum << "\t" << g << " exp2 p4" << endl;
}
```

Execution with:
`for i in {1..100}; do ./empty.bin && ./exp2_p4.bin && ./exp_p4.bin && ./exp.bin && ./exp2.bin; done`

where the file name tells whether the executable calls exp or exp2, and whether the summation is grouped by 4 (p4) or not.

### Results

The table below shows the average runtime (time), the standard deviation in ms, and the fastest case.

```
|   name  | time (ms) | std (ms) | smallest (ms) |
|:-------:|:---------:|:--------:|:-------------:|
|  empty  |   244.7   |   26.2   |     130.9     |
|   exp   |   591.7   |   95.8   |     422.5     |
|   exp2  |   536.5   |   85.4   |     393.7     |
|  exp p4 |   612.3   |   89.6   |     433.2     |
| exp2 p4 |   557.2   |   87.6   |     396.8     |
```

For one operation, one needs to divide it with `1e7`. I approximate the cost of the exponential by subtracting the time of the empty version (i.e. do the loop and summation without calculating the exp) from the exponential ones. These values are shown below:

[image: A figure showing the time costs of exp and exp2]

### Conclusion

exp2 can be around 11% faster than exp on Intel Xeon with gcc even if `-ffast-math` is on, in agreement with the accepted answer.

The manual loop unrolling by grouping the summation into a group of four does not help.

Answer (score 0):

- Should exp2 be (theoretically) faster than exp?

Yes.
The only way for x86 FPU to perform an exponentiation for non-integer power is using an instruction `F2XM1` which calculates **2<sup>x</sup>-1**.
No **e<sup>x</sup>** instruction exists on x86.
Any C library code for x86 is forced to calculate both `exp` and `exp2` using **2<sup>x</sup>**.

---

- Should there be any measurable differences?

No.
The difference is only single FPU multiplication, which is very fast for modern processors.

---

- Has the answer changed in the recent years?

Yes.
15-20 years ago price of multiplication was much higher than price of other operations.  Nowadays, multiplication is almost as cheap as addition.

Comment: No one uses F2XM1 to implement either `exp( )` or `exp2( )` nowadays, unless they're writing the laziest possible implementation.  SSE-based implementations are significantly faster, despite not having special instruction support.

Comment: @StephenCanon - Why polynomial approximation (10-20 SSE instructions) appears to be faster than single F2XM1 FPU instruction?

Comment: Because F2XM1 requires ~50-70+ cycles, depending on micro-architecture, and isn't pipelined at all. In 50 cycles, a Haswell can execute 800 double-precision FLOPs (vector; 200 scalar FLOPs is perhaps more relevant) and hundreds of integer instructions at the same time.