# How to efficiently raise 2 to a fractional power in C++?

Tags: c++, algorithm, performance, floating-point, c++20

I want to efficiently raise two to a rational power. This would be the foundation of all my other mathematical function implementations (`log, log2, exp, sin, cos`) because I use Newton's method and loads of the iteration schemes involve exponentiation.

I want to implement methods faster than cmath. Because we use binary computers, a lot of things related to the number two can be bit hacked.

The single precision floating point format uses 32 bits to represent fractions, the first bit is the sign bit, the next 8 bits are the exponent with a bias of 127, and the next 24 bits encode the fraction. For double precision the exponent is encoded as 11 bits with a bias of 1023 and the mantissa is 52 bits.

My idea is simple, I use the power rule of multiplication, in this case 2<sup>a</sup> * 2<sup>b</sup> = 2<sup>a + b</sup>. For a fractional exponent e, its decimal part d is e % 1 and then its integral part is i = e - d. Because the way floating point is encoded we can just assemble the final floating point representation by combining two parts, the exponent and the mantissa. i with its bias goes straight to the exponent part.

The mantissa part is a bit trickier, but there are hacks. The mantissa is encoded as a binary fractional number with implicit integral part of one, we can just add one to d to get the binary fraction from float bits. Note if d is negative then it should be added to two instead of one.

The next steps would be simple, the first bit corresponds to 2<sup>0.5</sup> the second 2<sup>0.25</sup> the third 2<sup>0.125</sup> et cetera. The important thing is they are constants so they can be stored in a lookup table. So for the fractional power find the set bits of the mantissa and multiply a number initialized to one with the corresponding value in the lookup table.

This gives the mantissa for the final value. Subtract one and multiply the difference by 1 << 23 for float and 1 << 52 for double. The result is assembled from bit casting (e << p) | m. For floats the worst case is 23 multiplications and for doubles 52 multiplications.

My code:

```
#include <array>
#include <bitset>
#include <chrono>
#include <cmath>
#include <iostream>
#include <utility>
#include <vector>

using std::array;
using std::chrono::steady_clock;
using std::chrono::duration;
using std::cout;
using std::vector;
float r = 0.0;

const array<double, 52> EXP2_BITS = [] {
    array<double, 52> exp2a;
    for (int i = 1; i < 53; i++) {
        exp2a[i - 1] = exp2(1.0 / (int64_t(1) << i));
    }
    return exp2a;
}();
constexpr int F52 = 1 << 23;
inline float fast_exp2_f(float f) {
    float frac = fmodf(f, 1.0f);
    int i, e;
    e = f - frac + 127;
    frac += frac >= 0 ? 1 : 2;
    uint32_t bits = std::bit_cast<uint32_t>(frac);
    uint32_t m = bits & 0x7fffff;
    i = 22;
    double p = 1.0;
    while (m) {
        if (m & 1) {
            p *= EXP2_BITS[i];
        }
        m >>= 1;
        i--;
    }
    uint32_t m1 = (p - 1.0) * F52;
    return std::bit_cast<float>((e << 23) | m1);
}

template <size_t N, size_t... I>
inline double exp2_helper_impl(std::bitset<N> m, std::index_sequence<I...>) {
    double p = 1.0;
    ((p *= std::get<I>(m)), ...);
    return p;
}

template <std::size_t N>
inline double exp2_helper(const std::bitset<N>& m) {
    return exp2_helper_impl(m, std::make_index_sequence<N>{});
}

inline float fast_exp2_f1(float f) {
    float frac = fmodf(f, 1.0f);
    int i, e;
    e = f - frac + 127;
    frac += frac >= 0 ? 1 : 2;
    uint32_t bits = std::bit_cast<uint32_t>(frac);
    std::bitset<23> m(bits & 0x7fffff);
    double p = exp2_helper(m);
    uint32_t m1 = (p - 1.0) * F52;
    return std::bit_cast<float>((e << 23) | m1);
}

int main()
{
    cout << std::setprecision(7);
    vector<float> bases(256);
    vector<int> ns(256);
    float r256 = 1.0 / 256;
    for (int i = 0; i < 256; i++) {
        bases[i] = 1.0 + rand() % 120 + (rand() % 256) * r256;
        ns[i] = 2 + rand() % 30;
    }
    auto start = steady_clock::now();
    for (int64_t i = 0; i < 1048576; i++) {
        r += fast_exp2_f(bases[i % 256]);
    }
    auto end = steady_clock::now();
    duration<double, std::nano> time = end - start;
    cout << "fast_exp2_f: " << time.count() / 1048576 << " nanoseconds\n";
    start = steady_clock::now();
    for (int64_t i = 0; i < 1048576; i++) {
        r += exp2f(bases[i % 256]);
    }
    end = steady_clock::now();
    time = end - start;
    cout << "exp2f: " << time.count() / 1048576 << " nanoseconds\n";
        start = steady_clock::now();
    for (int64_t i = 0; i < 1048576; i++) {
        r += fast_exp2_f1(bases[i % 256]);
    }
    end = steady_clock::now();
    time = end - start;
    cout << "fast_exp2_f1: " << time.count() / 1048576 << " nanoseconds\n";
    float n;
    for (int i = 0; i < 256; i++) {
        n = bases[i];
        cout << "n: " << n << ", fast_exp2_f: " << fast_exp2_f(n) << ", fast_exp2_f1: " << fast_exp2_f1(n) << ", exp2f: " << exp2f(n) << '\n';
    }
}
```

My method works and is very accurate, but it is slower:

```
fast_exp2_f: 57.74498 nanoseconds
exp2f: 36.58924 nanoseconds
n: 42.13672, fast_exp2_f: 4.83522e+12, exp2f: 4.83522e+12
n: 101.8789, fast_exp2_f: 4.66237e+30, exp2f: 4.66237e+30
n: 79.67969, fast_exp2_f: 9.682243e+23, exp2f: 9.682243e+23
n: 105.2852, fast_exp2_f: 4.942994e+31, exp2f: 4.942994e+31
n: 2.730469, fast_exp2_f: 6.636712, exp2f: 6.636713
n: 12.69922, fast_exp2_f: 6650.369, exp2f: 6650.369
n: 28.23438, fast_exp2_f: 3.157867e+08, exp2f: 3.157867e+08
n: 85.24219, fast_exp2_f: 4.575677e+25, exp2f: 4.575677e+25
n: 53.36719, fast_exp2_f: 1.161781e+16, exp2f: 1.161781e+16
n: 117.0234, fast_exp2_f: 1.688748e+35, exp2f: 1.688748e+35
n: 48.86719, fast_exp2_f: 5.134394e+14, exp2f: 5.134394e+14
n: 19.30078, fast_exp2_f: 645823.8, exp2f: 645823.9
n: 108.7305, fast_exp2_f: 5.384341e+32, exp2f: 5.384341e+32
n: 55.12109, fast_exp2_f: 3.918344e+16, exp2f: 3.918345e+16
n: 3.488281, fast_exp2_f: 11.22218, exp2f: 11.22218
n: 105.1445, fast_exp2_f: 4.483919e+31, exp2f: 4.483919e+31
n: 54.82812, fast_exp2_f: 3.198234e+16, exp2f: 3.198234e+16
n: 45.58594, fast_exp2_f: 5.281223e+13, exp2f: 5.281224e+13
n: 118.2305, fast_exp2_f: 3.898679e+35, exp2f: 3.898679e+35
n: 22.53516, fast_exp2_f: 6077962, exp2f: 6077962
n: 77.85547, fast_exp2_f: 2.734207e+23, exp2f: 2.734207e+23
n: 43.125, fast_exp2_f: 9.592207e+12, exp2f: 9.592208e+12
n: 41.92969, fast_exp2_f: 4.188839e+12, exp2f: 4.188839e+12
n: 89.21094, fast_exp2_f: 7.164207e+26, exp2f: 7.164207e+26
n: 51.28516, fast_exp2_f: 2.743913e+15, exp2f: 2.743913e+15
n: 111.6172, fast_exp2_f: 3.982185e+33, exp2f: 3.982185e+33
n: 34.85938, fast_exp2_f: 3.116861e+10, exp2f: 3.116861e+10
n: 24.07812, fast_exp2_f: 1.771079e+07, exp2f: 1.771079e+07
n: 37.25, fast_exp2_f: 1.634434e+11, exp2f: 1.634434e+11
n: 57.41797, fast_exp2_f: 1.925444e+17, exp2f: 1.925444e+17
n: 25.71484, fast_exp2_f: 5.507307e+07, exp2f: 5.507307e+07
n: 44.62891, fast_exp2_f: 2.720442e+13, exp2f: 2.720442e+13
n: 39.13281, fast_exp2_f: 6.027682e+11, exp2f: 6.027683e+11
n: 102.8789, fast_exp2_f: 9.324739e+30, exp2f: 9.324739e+30
n: 80.85156, fast_exp2_f: 2.181451e+24, exp2f: 2.181451e+24
n: 91.59766, fast_exp2_f: 3.746641e+27, exp2f: 3.746641e+27
n: 114.4453, fast_exp2_f: 2.827951e+34, exp2f: 2.827951e+34
n: 66.17188, fast_exp2_f: 8.312262e+19, exp2f: 8.312262e+19
n: 31.76953, fast_exp2_f: 3.660849e+09, exp2f: 3.660849e+09
n: 94.91016, fast_exp2_f: 3.722236e+28, exp2f: 3.722236e+28
n: 107.9141, fast_exp2_f: 3.057523e+32, exp2f: 3.057523e+32
n: 37.32422, fast_exp2_f: 1.720717e+11, exp2f: 1.720717e+11
n: 16.83594, fast_exp2_f: 116982.8, exp2f: 116982.9
```

So I wanted to optimize it. I think the performance bottleneck is the while loop, I have seen that using an index sequence with inline to unroll the loop can make the code [run in less than 2 nanoseconds](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77144800/how-to-efficiently-apply-polynomials-in-c-without-a-loop), and using a while loop to convert an integer to binary is a terribly inefficient way, the integers are already stored as binary internally, so we should access the binary directly.

I tried to use index sequence with bitset and that didn't work. It results compile failure. Error message:

```
D:\MyScript\CodeBlocks\testapp\main.cpp:103:23: error: no matching function for call to 'get<0>(std::bitset<23>&)'
```

My first method works, I compiled it with:

```
g++.exe -Wall -fexceptions -fomit-frame-pointer -fexpensive-optimizations -flto -O3 -m64 --std=c++20 -march=native -ffast-math  -c D:\MyScript\CodeBlocks\testapp\main.cpp -o obj\Release\main.o
g++.exe  -o bin\Release\testapp.exe obj\Release\main.o  -O3 -flto -s -static-libstdc++ -static-libgcc -static -m64
```

How can I optimize this?

---

For whatever it is worth, I have manually unrolled the loop and it does make the code faster, as expected, however it is ugly and not as efficient as it can be:

```
inline float fast_exp2_f1(float f) {
    int e = int(f);
    float frac = f - e;
    e += 127;
    frac += frac >= 0 ? 1 : 2;
    uint32_t bits = std::bit_cast<uint32_t>(frac);
    std::bitset<23> m(bits & 0x7fffff);
    double p = 1.0;
    if (m[0]) {p *= EXP2_BITS[22]; }
    if (m[1]) {p *= EXP2_BITS[21]; }
    if (m[2]) {p *= EXP2_BITS[20]; }
    if (m[3]) {p *= EXP2_BITS[19]; }
    if (m[4]) {p *= EXP2_BITS[18]; }
    if (m[5]) {p *= EXP2_BITS[17]; }
    if (m[6]) {p *= EXP2_BITS[16]; }
    if (m[7]) {p *= EXP2_BITS[15]; }
    if (m[8]) {p *= EXP2_BITS[14]; }
    if (m[9]) {p *= EXP2_BITS[13]; }
    if (m[10]) {p *= EXP2_BITS[12]; }
    if (m[11]) {p *= EXP2_BITS[11]; }
    if (m[12]) {p *= EXP2_BITS[10]; }
    if (m[13]) {p *= EXP2_BITS[9]; }
    if (m[14]) {p *= EXP2_BITS[8]; }
    if (m[15]) {p *= EXP2_BITS[7]; }
    if (m[16]) {p *= EXP2_BITS[6]; }
    if (m[17]) {p *= EXP2_BITS[5]; }
    if (m[18]) {p *= EXP2_BITS[4]; }
    if (m[19]) {p *= EXP2_BITS[3]; }
    if (m[20]) {p *= EXP2_BITS[2]; }
    if (m[21]) {p *= EXP2_BITS[1]; }
    if (m[22]) {p *= EXP2_BITS[0]; }
    uint32_t m1 = (p - 1.0) * F23;
    return std::bit_cast<float>((e << 23) | m1);
}
```

```
fast_exp2_f: 50.11549 nanoseconds
exp2f: 36.29322 nanoseconds
fast_exp2_f1: 11.36074 nanoseconds
```

---

I have now converted my code to branchless form:

```
const array<double, 104> EXP2_BITS = [] {
    array<double, 104> exp2a;
    for (int i = 1; i < 53; i++) {
        exp2a[i * 2 - 2] = 1.0;
        exp2a[i * 2 - 1] = exp2(1.0 / (int64_t(1) << i));
    }
    return exp2a;
}();

constexpr int F23 = 1 << 23;
inline float fast_exp2_f1(float f) {
    int e = int(f);
    float frac = f - e;
    e += 127;
    frac += frac >= 0 ? 1 : 2;
    uint32_t bits = std::bit_cast<uint32_t>(frac);
    std::bitset<23> m(bits & 0x7fffff);
    double p = 1.0;
    p *= EXP2_BITS[44+m[0]];
    p *= EXP2_BITS[42+m[1]];
    p *= EXP2_BITS[40+m[2]];
    p *= EXP2_BITS[38+m[3]];
    p *= EXP2_BITS[36+m[4]];
    p *= EXP2_BITS[34+m[5]];
    p *= EXP2_BITS[32+m[6]];
    p *= EXP2_BITS[30+m[7]];
    p *= EXP2_BITS[28+m[8]];
    p *= EXP2_BITS[26+m[9]];
    p *= EXP2_BITS[24+m[10]];
    p *= EXP2_BITS[22+m[11]];
    p *= EXP2_BITS[20+m[12]];
    p *= EXP2_BITS[18+m[13]];
    p *= EXP2_BITS[16+m[14]];
    p *= EXP2_BITS[14+m[15]];
    p *= EXP2_BITS[12+m[16]];
    p *= EXP2_BITS[10+m[17]];
    p *= EXP2_BITS[8+m[18]];
    p *= EXP2_BITS[6+m[19]];
    p *= EXP2_BITS[4+m[20]];
    p *= EXP2_BITS[2+m[21]];
    p *= EXP2_BITS[0+m[22]];
    uint32_t m1 = (p - 1.0) * F23;
    return std::bit_cast<float>((e << 23) | m1);
}
```

It should be more stable and the conditional overhead is eliminated. But there is a multiplication assignment overhead for each bit, so the code takes longer to execute.

```
fast_exp2_f1: 20.96491 nanoseconds
```

---

I have done it. I have beaten `exp2f` conclusively.

```
const array<double, 52> EXP2_BITS = [] {
    array<double, 52> exp2a;
    for (int i = 1; i < 53; i++) {
        exp2a[i - 1] = exp2(1.0 / (int64_t(1) << i));
    }
    return exp2a;
}();

constexpr int F23 = 1 << 23;
inline float fast_exp2_f(float f) {
    int e = int(f);
    float frac = f - e;
    e += 127;
    frac += frac >= 0 ? 1 : 2;
    uint32_t bits = std::bit_cast<uint32_t>(frac);
    std::bitset<23> m(bits & 0x7fffff);
    double p = 1.0;
    p *= m[0] ? EXP2_BITS[22] : 1;
    p *= m[1] ? EXP2_BITS[21] : 1;
    p *= m[2] ? EXP2_BITS[20] : 1;
    p *= m[3] ? EXP2_BITS[19] : 1;
    p *= m[4] ? EXP2_BITS[18] : 1;
    p *= m[5] ? EXP2_BITS[17] : 1;
    p *= m[6] ? EXP2_BITS[16] : 1;
    p *= m[7] ? EXP2_BITS[15] : 1;
    p *= m[8] ? EXP2_BITS[14] : 1;
    p *= m[9] ? EXP2_BITS[13] : 1;
    p *= m[10] ? EXP2_BITS[12] : 1;
    p *= m[11] ? EXP2_BITS[11] : 1;
    p *= m[12] ? EXP2_BITS[10] : 1;
    p *= m[13] ? EXP2_BITS[9] : 1;
    p *= m[14] ? EXP2_BITS[8] : 1;
    p *= m[15] ? EXP2_BITS[7] : 1;
    p *= m[16] ? EXP2_BITS[6] : 1;
    p *= m[17] ? EXP2_BITS[5] : 1;
    p *= m[18] ? EXP2_BITS[4] : 1;
    p *= m[19] ? EXP2_BITS[3] : 1;
    p *= m[20] ? EXP2_BITS[2] : 1;
    p *= m[21] ? EXP2_BITS[1] : 1;
    p *= m[22] ? EXP2_BITS[0] : 1;
    uint32_t m1 = (p - 1.0) * F23;
    return std::bit_cast<float>((e << 23) | m1);
}
```

The above remains faster even with 32768 random values in the array.

```
fast_exp2_f: 11.4665 nanoseconds
exp2f: 36.11965 nanoseconds
```

But there is still the conditional overhead.

Comment: You may want to specify "raise two to a rational power" in more detail. All numeric binary floating-point operands *are* rational number (fractions), so you may be inquiring about something like `exp2f()`, a sample implementation of which in ISO-C99 is provided [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29381117/which-exponentiation-algorithms-do-cpu-programming-languages-use).

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30222836/should-exp2-be-faster-than-exp) seems related too.

Comment: This question should specific what degree of precision is expected. Do you need perfect precision down to the last digit in an IEEE float? Do you need to consider the rounding mode in the floating point environment? What level of CPU extensions are you willing to rely on? If any, is it acceptable to run-time-switch using `cpuid`? Do you want to avoid inline assembly and/or intrinsics completely? So many questions that need to be answered ...

Comment: There's a single FPU (x87) instruction which does this (minus 1). I suspect it would be hard to beat that in accuracy and performance on x86 CPUs. See f2xm1 on https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/X86_Assembly/Floating_Point

Comment: There is also an AVX-512 instruction https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/vexp2ps which computes 2^X without -1. The glibc implementation uses the x87 instruction already afaik, so it's unlikely that you could beat it no matter what code you write. If the glibc method isn't accurate enough, you should probably just refine it with Newton's method or something to make it slightly more accurate, but otherwise use the standard library.

Comment: If you want to do this portably, it is better to use the `<cmath>` function `ldexp` rather than bit casting -- `ldexp(x, e)` where `x` is a `double` and `e` is an `int` computes x2^e

Comment: @SimonGoater `f2xm1` actually takes quite a long time and it works on the 80-bit wide (i.e. `long double` type). For example, on Skylake, it has a latency of 65-80 cycles. A LUT-based implementation can be significantly faster if the cache is hot (at least for an implementation operating on 32-bit FP numbers). SIMD implementations are even faster, but it's difficult to achieve strict IEEE-754 compliance (though the OP does not seems to care about that anyway).

Comment: @JanSchultke `VEXP2PS` requires the AVX512ER instruction set which is only supported by very few processors. The last Xeons Phi (KNL and KNM) are the only one to support such instructions. Xeon Phi are discontinued and now quite obsolete. The standard way to implement such a function efficiently with SIMD instructions is to use many FMAs (for the precise approx typically based on chebyshev polynomials) + roundps/cvttps/andps (and few others). The Intel SVML does such a thing.

Comment: I'd be surprised if you could beat the FPU at this. Is the game really worth the candle?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**TL;DR:** the implementation is bound by the chain of *dependent conditional jumps* on GCC. Clang produces a better assembly code (thanks to SIMD instructions and a branchless code). The benchmark is clearly *biased*. Scalar `exp2f` implementations are inefficient compared to SIMD ones, so you should use the later if possible.

---

### Analysis

The main issue with `fast_exp2_f1` is the long **chain of dependent conditional instructions**. Indeed, here is a part of the generated code with GCC:

```
[...]
.L33:
        test    ah, 16
        je      .L34
        vmulsd  xmm0, xmm0, QWORD PTR .LC21[rip]
.L34:
        test    ah, 32
        je      .L35
        vmulsd  xmm0, xmm0, QWORD PTR .LC22[rip]
.L35:
        test    ah, 64
        je      .L36
        vmulsd  xmm0, xmm0, QWORD PTR .LC23[rip]
.L36:
        test    ah, -128
        je      .L37
        vmulsd  xmm0, xmm0, QWORD PTR .LC24[rip]
.L37:
        test    eax, 65536
        je      .L38
        vmulsd  xmm0, xmm0, QWORD PTR .LC25[rip]
.L38:
        test    eax, 131072
        je      .L39
        vmulsd  xmm0, xmm0, QWORD PTR .LC26[rip]
.L39:
        test    eax, 262144
        je      .L40
        vmulsd  xmm0, xmm0, QWORD PTR .LC27[rip]
[...]
```

The processor need to evaluate either a conditional jump is taken or not and then jump accordingly. When a conditional jump is taken, the processor cannot do it faster than in 1 cycle. The thing is you have 23 conditional jumps, so it cannot be faster than 23 cycles if all are taken. On my i5-9600KF processor, this means at least 5.11 ns only for the chain of conditions. If a jump is not taken then the **FMA latency** is the bottleneck since a double-precision multiplication typically take about 2-8 cycles on most mainstream machines. On my i5-9600KF processor, it takes 4 cycles. Thus, if all conditional jumps are not taken, the code takes at least `23*4=92` cycles, since all multiplication operations are dependent. Please note that the processor cannot reorder them due to the *non-associativity* of double-precision numbers, and while compilers could theoretically reorder them, this is a too complex case for them due to the conditions. In practice, there is a mixture of taken and not-taken conditional jumps so the FMA latency is only an issue if several conditional jumps are not taken. It turns out most conditional jumps are taken in your benchmark but not all of them. In fact, in average, 4 conditional jumps are not taken and all others are. This means any of the conditional jumps have a 83% chance to be taken.

The cost of conditional jumps is variable and hard to predict. When a conditional jump is taken, the instructions to be executed need first to be fetched and decoded from a different non-contiguous location in memory. The thing is the outcome is dependent of data produced by other parts of the pipeline. This can introduce a significant overhead due to **pipeline stalls** (typically >10 cycles). Modern mainstream processors are very complex and they are designed by smart engineers and researchers for decades who tried to reduce this overhead as much as possible. Mainstream processors now [**predict conditional jumps**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11227902/12939557) so to reduce pipeline stalls. When a condition is well predicted, there is generally (nearly) no pipeline stalls on recent mainstream processors. When there is a **miss-prediction**, the overhead can be huge, especially here due to the long chain of conditional jumps.

It turns out that my processor (like most recent mainstream ones) is able to predict many conditional jumps. In fact, it is able to know whether a jumps is taken based on the actual number being computed. Well, this is a huge simplification since what happens in practice is far more complex (branch prediction is a very complex topic). Indeed, there is only 256 numbers in the input array of double-precision numbers, so **the processor can remember the outcome of most conditional jumps for the 256 numbers** in order to successfully predict them (which is pretty insane by the way). Put it shortly, this means **the benchmark is biased** due to processor optimizations. This can be seen on my machine by increasing the number of items in the input array from 256 to 32768 (quick check using Clang without `-ffast-math` on Windows generating a code close to GCC):

```
256 items:
 - fast_exp2_f: 44.950962 nanoseconds
 - exp2f: 40.409470 nanoseconds
 - fast_exp2_f1: 13.479328 nanoseconds

32768 items:
 - fast_exp2_f: 68.788147 nanoseconds
 - exp2f: 40.300083 nanoseconds
 - fast_exp2_f1: 45.244217 nanoseconds
```

One can see that `exp2f` is not affected by the number of items in the input array. This is because there are either no conditional jumps within it or few that are well predicted (i.e. not much dependent of the actual input numbers used in the benchmark). In the end, **`fast_exp2_f1` is actually slower than `exp2f`** in a more realistic use-case. In fact, input numbers tends to be close to each other so `fast_exp2_f1` has an advantage over `exp2f`. Using input random numbers with a wider range should slow down `fast_exp2_f1` even more. On my machine, it should take significantly more than 60 ns.

---

### How to make the code faster

In general, a simple solution to avoid branch miss-prediction issues is just to write a **branchless** code. This is possible here on x86-64 processor thanks to SIMD (SSE) instructions like `blendpd`. However, this is not a good solution here since most conditional jumps are taken and so most multiplications are not performed. Using a naive branchless code would cause the FMA latency to be an issue (at least 20 ns on my machine for this part of the code).

A smarter solution is to do a **binary reduction** of the multiplication combined with blending. Doing this yourself is tedious, not portable and low-level. Indeed, GCC tends not to generate branchless code and AFAIK there is no way to force it using a portable code. Thus, SIMD (SSE) intrinsics are the way to go to do such an optimization. In fact, one can use SIMD instructions to operate on multiple numbers at once. It turns out Clang do that pretty well with **`-O3 -ffast-math`**. Here is the part of the code generated by Clang:

```
        vpand   ymm6, ymm0, ymmword ptr [rip + .LCPI1_5]
        vpand   ymm7, ymm0, ymmword ptr [rip + .LCPI1_6]
        vpand   ymm8, ymm0, ymmword ptr [rip + .LCPI1_7]
        vpand   ymm9, ymm0, ymmword ptr [rip + .LCPI1_8]
        vpcmpeqq        ymm9, ymm9, ymm3
        vpcmpeqq        ymm7, ymm7, ymm3
        vpcmpeqq        ymm6, ymm6, ymm3
        vmovupd xmm10, xmmword ptr [rip + EXP2_BITS+168]
        vunpcklpd       xmm5, xmm10, xmm5       # xmm5 = xmm10[0],xmm5[0]
        vpermpd ymm10, ymmword ptr [rip + EXP2_BITS+152], 20 # ymm10 = mem[0,1,1,0]
        vblendpd        ymm5, ymm5, ymm10, 12           # ymm5 = ymm5[0,1],ymm10[2,3]
        vblendvpd       ymm5, ymm5, ymmword ptr [rip + .LCPI1_9], ymm7
        vpermpd ymm7, ymmword ptr [rip + EXP2_BITS+120], 27 # ymm7 = mem[3,2,1,0]
        vpermpd ymm10, ymmword ptr [rip + EXP2_BITS+88], 27 # ymm10 = mem[3,2,1,0]
        vblendvpd       ymm6, ymm10, ymm4, ymm6
        vpermpd ymm10, ymmword ptr [rip + EXP2_BITS+56], 27 # ymm10 = mem[3,2,1,0]
        vpcmpeqq        ymm3, ymm8, ymm3
        vblendvpd       ymm3, ymm10, ymm4, ymm3
        vblendvpd       ymm4, ymm7, ymm4, ymm9
        vmulpd  ymm3, ymm4, ymm3
        vmulpd  ymm3, ymm6, ymm3
        vmulpd  ymm3, ymm5, ymm3
        vextractf128    xmm4, ymm3, 1
        vmulpd  xmm3, xmm3, xmm4
        vshufpd xmm4, xmm3, xmm3, 1             # xmm4 = xmm3[1,0]
        vmulsd  xmm3, xmm3, xmm4
        vextractf128    xmm4, ymm2, 1
        vmulpd  xmm2, xmm2, xmm4
        vshufpd xmm4, xmm2, xmm2, 1             # xmm4 = xmm2[1,0]
        vmulsd  xmm2, xmm2, xmm4
        vpand   xmm0, xmm0, xmmword ptr [rip + .LCPI1_10]
        vxorpd  xmm4, xmm4, xmm4
        vpcmpeqq        xmm0, xmm0, xmm4
        vmovupd xmm4, xmmword ptr [rip + EXP2_BITS+8]
        vblendvpd       xmm0, xmm4, xmmword ptr [rip + .LCPI1_11], xmm0
```

One can note the `vmulpd` operating on multiple values at once, the `vpand`, `vpcmpeqq` and `vblendvpd` so to execution the conditions in a branchless way. This code is relatively fast and independent of the input values:

```
256 items:
 - fast_exp2_f: 43.608665 nanoseconds
 - exp2f: 40.797138 nanoseconds
 - fast_exp2_f1: 15.594292 nanoseconds

32768 items:
 - fast_exp2_f: 70.216560 nanoseconds
 - exp2f: 41.187191 nanoseconds
 - fast_exp2_f1: 16.847897 nanoseconds
```

One can see that the timings of `fast_exp2_f1` are left unaffected by the size of the input array. In fact, `fast_exp2_f1` is faster than `exp2f`.

Put it shortly: use Clang here if you can.

---

### Notes

All implementations are inefficient in this case. You can use SIMD instructions so to operate on multiple input values at once. This is more efficient than what Clang does for `fast_exp2_f1` using `-ffast-math` (i.e. vectorizing the function which still operate on 1 input value at a time). Most optimized math libraries does that (like the Intel SVML, or ISPC, or even the standard math library of Sony on PS4/PS5). I expect such optimized libraries be significantly faster than 10 ns/item on my machine. However, they often introduce a small error of few [ULP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unit_in_the_last_place). This should not be an issue in your case since you use `-ffast-math` anyway.

Just for fun, I tried using ISPC in your benchmark. It looks like ISPC does not implement `exp2f`, but there is `pow` which might be slower than computing `exp2f` directly (because `pow` often compute a `log` and an `exp` but I am not sure with a constant base being 2). ISPC is much much faster than all implementations in your benchmark as expected (with a >=5 digit precision). It is **>30 times faster** than the other implementation on my machine (thanks to the AVX-2 SIMD instruction set and an aggressively optimized branchless computation):

```
ISPC pow(2.0f,x): 0.417328 nanoseconds
```

I advise you not to reinvent the wheel, use an SIMD implementation is possible, and read research papers about it. Implementing faster exponential functions than optimized math libraries while providing at least the same accuracy is very hard, even for highly skilled developers.